# How to create ID column in R

Tags: r, database

I have a longitudinal data in a long format. I want to create an ID variable based on the variable-column that identifies each observation of my data. How do I do that in R?

Example: I have this data

```
name year var1 var2
 A    1    4    3
 A    2    5    1
 A    3    4    2
 B    1    .    .
 B    2    4    3
 B    3    5    1
```

I want to produce a new column called 'id' with a unique number for every name, such as:

```
name id year var1 var2
 A    1  1    4    3
 A    1  2    5    1
 A    1  3    4    2
 B    2  1    .    .
 B    2  2    4    3
 B    2  3    5    1
```

Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your `name` column doesn't just contain single letters (or even if it does), you can use:

```
dat$id <- as.numeric(as.factor(dat$name))
```

or, more simply:

```
dat$id <- c(as.factor(dat$name))
```

where `dat` is your `data.frame`.

Answer (score 2):

```
tc='
name year var1 var2
A    1    4    3
A    2    5    1
A    3    4    2
B    1    .    .
B    2    4    3
B    3    5    1'

df <- read.table(text=tc, header=T)

df$ID <- match(df$name, LETTERS)
```

Although is not clear if name is a column or are the rownames of the data frame.
If is not a column then try `rownames(df)` instead of `df$name`

Comment: I think `text=tc` should be replaced with `textConnection(tc)`.

Comment: @jbaums `text` is a new argument to read.table, which helps to avoid `textConnection`. Cuts out the middle man, if you will.

Comment: Thanks @RomanLuštrik, and sorry AndresT. I admit I'm still on 2.13 on the laptop I was using, and it seems the `text` argument is not yet implemented in that version. I have an edit in the queue, but hopefully it doesn't get approved. If so, feel free to change it back!