# Conditional sequence

Tags: r, sequence

I would like to make an ID number for each unique name. Data could look like this:

```
dat <- read.table(text='name    value   etc1    etc2
                          A        9      20       X
                          A       10      10       X
                          A       11       1       Y
                          B        2       5       Y
                          C       40      40       Y
                          C       50       2       Y',header=TRUE)
```

What I mean is that I would like to create a new column
`ID` which is 1 when `name` is "A", 2 when `name` is B so forth.
The result should look like this:

```
  dat <- read.table(text=' ID    name    value   etc1    etc2
                           1      A        9      20       X
                           1      A       10      10       X
                           1      A       11       1       Y
                           2      B        2       5       Y
                           3      C       40      40       Y
                           3      C       50       2       Y',header=TRUE)
```

My data frame is much bigger than this example, so what I am looking for is a general solution. 
Hope someone can help, I have no clue on how to start.

Comment: In your case just `as.numeric(dat$name)` will work. Maybe a bit more general solution could be `library(data.table) ; setDT(dat)[, ID := .GRP, by = name]` or just `match(dat$name, unique(dat$name))`

Comment: This has been asked countless times before. First Google hit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9289258/how-to-create-id-column-in-r